# Not able to load React Components from a subdirectory in a typescript project

Tags: typescript

I created a directory called "components" under the src directory and then moved my React component inside that directory as App.tsx

I modified my tsconfig.json as

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "jsx": "react",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "outDir": "./build/",
      "baseUrl": "./src",
      "preserveConstEnums": true,
      "removeComments": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "target": "es5",
      "paths": {
         "~/*": ["./*"]
      }
   },
   "include": [
      "./src/**/*"
   ],
   "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "**/*.spec.ts"
   ]
}
```

At the end of my webpack.config.js I added the line

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ["js", "ts", "tsx", "*"] 
}
```

Now in my index.tsx I do

```
import { App } from './components/App'
```

but when I do `nom start` I get an error

```
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/App' in '/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/react-ts-todo/src'
 @ ./src/index.tsx 5:12-39
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.tsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/querystring-es3/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './decode' in '/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/react-ts-todo/node_modules/querystring-es3'
 @ ./node_modules/querystring-es3/index.js 3:33-52
 @ ./node_modules/url/url.js
 @ (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.tsx
```

I have checked in my code [here](https://github.com/abhsrivastava/react-ts-todo) just in case if you need to have a look at the sample application.

My React application works perfectly if I have everything inside of index.tsx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I solved it myself the webpack.config.js entry should be

```
resolve: {
  extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx"] 
}
```

I was missing the "." before the extension names.